# Locally connected and compact Hausdorff space invariant of continuous mappings

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, compactness, connectedness

I am looking for a reference (not proof) to the following theorem:

If $X$ is a compact and locally connected topological space, Y is a Hausdorff topological space, $f:X\to Y$ is continuous and $f(X)=Y$, then $Y$ is locally connected.

I found reference in Kuratowski, Topology II for the case where $X$ is metrizable. Any one knows about any reference to this case?

Comment: $X$ compact and $Y$ hausdorf means the map is a quotient map, right? is local connectivity preserved under quotients?

Comment: Yes, local connectivity is preserved under quotients. I have citation on that (after Engelking) Whyburn, On quasi-compact mappings, Duke Math J.19 (1952), 445-446.

Comment: oh, are you looking for like first recorded references?

Comment: no, I need to give any reliable referential support for this fact, not proving it myself. I think your solution is good enough as it's really elementary to notice that $f$ is quotient.

Comment: I added the reference request tag so that it's more clear you're looking for a published proof, and not just a proof.

Comment: I once stumbled upon a proof for this fact in Willard, *General Topology*.

Comment: What's wrong with just sketching a short proof (if there is one)?

Comment: @StefanH. Indeed, Theorem 27.12.