# Is the boundary of an arbitrary bounded simply-connected open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the image of a Jordan curve?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, algebraic-topology

I am trying to work out what the prerequisites are to the theorem that surfaces can always be triangulated. The key theorem seems to be Schoenflies' theorem, which depends on [Caratheodory's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_%28conformal_mapping%29).

The Wikipedia entry for Caratheodory's theorem states that if a map $f$ maps the unit disc conformally onto a a bounded open set $U$, then $f$ has a continuous injective extension to the closed disc if and only if $\partial U$ is a Jordan curve.

At least, that's my interpretation. I'm fairly convinced the article has a (repeated) typo, since it says the unit disk $D$ is what must have $\partial D$ be Jordan.... but discs trivially have such boundaries.

My question is then, have I misunderstood the conditions? Or is there an example of a bounded, non-empty, simply-connected, open set whose boundary is not the image of a Jordan curve.

Or, if I have misunderstood something, and in fact every bounded, non-empty simply-connected open *does* have such a boundary, how would you go about proving it?

Comment: I think I found a counter-example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463876/do-simply-connected-open-sets-in-bbb-r2-always-have-continuous-boundaries

Answer (score 5):

No, there are open, bounded, simply connected subsets $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\partial U$ is not a Jordan curve. Take for example
$$U = (-1,1)^2 \setminus \bigl( [0,1] \times \{0\} \bigr),$$
roughly speaking an open square with a segment removed. Then its boundary is
$$\partial U = \partial \bigl( [0,1]^2 \bigr) \cup \bigl( [0,1] \times \{0\} \bigr),$$
i.e. the boundary of the square together with a small "hair". This is not the image of a Jordan curve, because it's not homeomorphic to $S^1$.

Comment: Ah, that is a much simpler example.

Comment: I think do you mean "$\partial U=\partial\bigl(\boldsymbol{[-1,1]^2}\bigr)\cup\bigl([0,1]\times\{0\}\bigr)$".

Comment: Hi, thanks for your example. I have not studied homeomorphisms, I only know the definition. I see intuitively that you probably can't continuously deform the boundary in your example into $S^1,$ but is there a more solid way of thinking about it?